# How to create a rounded rectangle shape Css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

I'm trying to design a profile image shape just like this

[image: correct image design]

but my code given me the following design

[image: my design]

I'm worried about the white space inside the border and the shape here is code

```css
.doctor-profile-photo {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  border-radius: 60px/140px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #ccc;
}
.doctor-profile-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 60px/140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="doctor-profile-photo">
  <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/bird/bird-09.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: If you can, try removing the `<img>` tag and put the image in the background of the `.doctor-pofile-photo`. This will solve that thin white border issue. (I think :D)

Comment: Don't put same `border-radius` as the parent for the `img`. It needs to be lesser by border width if I am not wrong. Try `50px/130px` for `img` and that should remove the whitespace in the corners.

Comment: @NijrajGelani these are not static images, i have to manage all through back-end support so i think background image is not a right idea in that case

Comment: @KashifLatif Just add it as an inline style.

Comment: @Harry that's work for me thanks but what about shape?

Comment: @NijrajGelani, inner space is resolve now, can u help me on shape design? that's the big problem i'm facing right now

Comment: It is a good question. Please, let me know if nobody provides a solution within 2 days. I'll assign a bounty then to attract attention to the post.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderElgin for support

Comment: @NijrajGelani: why you delete your answer? i found that a bit useful for me

Comment: @KashifLatif I tried it. Wasn't really satisfied. I'll undelete it though if that was the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives pretty similar output to what you want. Try tweaking the values of border-radius and height-width to achieve exactly what you want.

```
<style>
 #pic { 
    position: relative;     
    width: 130px; 
    height: 150px; 
    margin: 20px 0; 
    background: red; 
    border-radius: 50% / 10%; 
    color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-indent: .1em;
 } 
 #pic:before { 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10%; 
    bottom: 10%; 
    right: -5%; 
    left: -5%; 
    background: inherit; 
    border-radius: 5% / 50%; 
 } 
</style>
<div id="pic"></div>
```

Here's a useful link : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: i'm trying it, give me a sec

Comment: @KashifLatif It won't really work, it'll just show the shape but you can't really put an image inside it. That's why I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

## SVg path and pattern

You can create your shape with a single path. I used a quadratic Bezier curve.
[Path MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

I added an image to the svg using a image tag and pattern tag.
This is then using inside the path with this `fill="url(#img1)"`.
The defs tag is used to hide elements we are not using directly.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="400">
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" />
    </pattern>

  </defs>
  <path d="M15,15 Q 50,0 85,18 100,50 85,85 50,100 18,85 0,50 15,15Z" fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```